# PostFix Blacklist Configuration

Tags: mysql, postfix, email-server, blacklist

I have setup up a basic email server using PostFix with Dovecot/IMAP. But i face some issue with the blacklist setup.

below is my postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/blacklist.cf reject_unauth_destination
```

blacklist.cf

```
user = mailuser
password = mailuser2011
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT 'REJECT' FROM blacklist WHERE email='%s' AND id=( SELECT id FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%u')
```

My SQL table have 2 columns for the blacklist. Namely the `id` and the `email` where id is the individual user and email is the blacklisted address.

What I want to do is to retrieve the address match from the database with reference to the recipient in the mail. If I hard code the email value to something existing in the database it will be able to reject mails from the blocked user.

However, if I uses the `%u`(which I assume it refers to the recipient), it fails to block at all.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup tables in Postfix are Key-Value-Lookups. That means you have a key and get a value after lookup. In your case (check_sender_access) the key is the sender; and only the sender. So your requirement of having two keys (sender and recipient) can not be done with Postfix.

The only way to solve that is by [Policy Delegation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html), where you have multiple keys (sender, recipient, IP, hostname, helo, ...) to do your lookup.

But on the other hand it is a very bad idea to rely on the sender address, as this is the easiest thing to forge.

Comment: Thanks, I will look up on the Policy Delegation. I know it's a bad idea that's but currently just trying to work with the address only. Finally someone answered me :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi there, I tried working my way around with the policy delegation. Somehow I don't really get it. Guess it's because I'm new to Perl. Is there any samples that I can look at other than this? I'm having the error of attributes.

Comment: This is not part of this question. You can use any programming language you are familiar with and which supports either Unix sockets or TCP/IP sockets. I did an implementation with Java without problems.